# How to search name and return to ABN or ACN number using php?

Tags: php, soap

I have to try to get name. If I will give name in search box it returns ABN/ACN number.
This is my code:

```
    public function searchByName($company_name){
        $params = new stdClass();
        $params->externalNameSearch();
        $params->authenticationGuid            = $this->guid;
        return $this->ABRSearchByName($params);
    }
 }

$abn_search_string = "11111111111"; 
$company_name ="A&SLEPTOSPTYLTD";
$abn_guid ="";
try{
   $abnlookup = new abnlookup($abn_guid);
    try{
       $result = $abnlookup->searchByName($company_name);
```

Please give to me some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Please use my function below its working for me you will get list in response object , you are invoking $params->externalNameSearch(); in wrong way. Also Please paste your GUID in code.

```
/*function searchByName 
@params - $company_name 
@returns - Object which contains request and response object. */

public function searchByName($company_name){

$erfnt = new stdClass();           // corresponds to ExternalRequestFilterNameType from WSDL
$erfnt->tradingName = "Y";      // for yes put 'Y', for no put 'N'
$erfnt->legalName = "Y";        

$erfsc = new stdClass();   //  corresponds to ExternalRequestFilterStateCode from WSDL
$erfsc->QLD = 'Y';        // for yes put 'Y', for no put 'N'
$erfsc->NT = 'Y';
$erfsc->SA = 'Y';
$erfsc->WA = 'Y';
$erfsc->VIC = 'Y';
$erfsc->ACT = 'Y';
$erfsc->TAS = 'Y';
$erfsc->NSW = 'Y';

$erf = new stdClass();
$erf->nameType = $erfnt;    
$erf->stateCode = $erfsc;   

$ens = new stdClass();
$ens->authenticationGUID =  ""; // paste your GUID here
$ens->name = $company_name;     
$ens->filters = $erf;           // corresponds to ExternalRequestFilters from WSDL 

$params = new stdClass();
$params->externalNameSearch         = $ens;         // corresponds to externalNameSearch
$params->authenticationGuid         = ""; // paste you GUID here.
return $this->ABRSearchByName($params);

}
```